# JSON and Python Django - can't get around same origin issue- callback function isn't called

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, json, highcharts

I call

> $.getJSON('http://localhost:8000/polls/?callback=?', function(data)

and recieve an error:

> Error: parsererror errorThrown: jQuery16103397698865741826_1320825997345 was not called

If I call a json file that is next to my html file it works fine.
If I call the google example url: `http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?` it also works.

Any ideas? I think that maybe it has something to do with DJango or the way I return from my server side code.

```
index(request):

    a = {}
    a[1320675940] = 1.8
    a[1320675941] = 2.8
    a[1320675942] = 38
    a[1320675943] = 4.8
    a[1320675944] = 5.8
    a[1320675945] = 6.8
    a[1320675946] = 7.8

    data = simplejson.dumps(a)

    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype="text/plain")
    #return HttpResponse(data, mimetype="json")
    #return HttpResponse(str(data), mimetype="text/plain")
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Comment: @tylerl I'm not convinced that this is the problem since the google url works and it is obviously not in my domain. I am not a web developer so I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: Do you get [valide JSON](http://jsonlint.com/) if you call `http://localhost:8000/polls/?callback=?` directly?

Comment: @PiTheNumber - yes. Ran the validator and it is valid

Comment: I think the JSON is not the focus here. It is the Django script I wrote. Since google returns a JSON-P format. That fails the validations of the site you reffered me. If this was the problem I'd get a JSON parse error - I think this error is for parsing the reponse packet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning JSON (with a plain text content-type), not JSON-P.

You need to look at the value of `callback` in the query string and wrap the JSON in that function call.

e.g. for `?callback=foo`:

```
foo(/* Your JSON here */);
```

You should also use the correct content type (`application/javascript`).

Comment: Thank you- that worked. Can you explain the why do I need to do this explicitly?

Comment: @AYBABTU — Because JSON-P works by defining a function, then loading a script that calls that function.